# User Login System for Prototype Business Application

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, authentication

I am creating a little .NET c# business application/prototype for work. I'm having a little fun to be honest. It relies on SQL 2012, C# .NET 4 WPF, and I plan on toying with the Entity Framework.

We have 5 users total and 3 roles. What is the best way to set up a solid user login system? This is a prototype and I just need it to work, but in principle I would like it to be solid so I can extend it for future purposes to maybe 10 or 15 users.

The system needs to be able to accept a new user and password and then to assign it a role.

Edit:

I am building the application to sit on a client machine which interacts with an internal server over the network to speak with the sql database.

Comment: You need to tell us how you are interfacing with SQL server. I'd assume some sort of middle-tier, most likely on a web-server, but there's no mention of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my proposal:

Build the DB this way

```
 User           UserRoles               Roles
---------       ---------------         ------------
UserID(PK)          UserID(FK)(PK)         RoleID(PK)
UserName            RoleID(FK)(PK)         RoleName
Password                                   RoleDescription
```

This DB model will set up a many to many relationship in EF for you to ensure users can belong to multiple roles. You can then create your own authentication model for your application since Membership Provider does not work with WPF but it should be simple though.

When you log in a user you can query the db using EF to know the roles a user belongs to so you can perform your desired actions on the results.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using InBuilt membership provider as it has most of the boiler plate code written for you and to be fair to Microsoft it's not too bad and is extensible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx

**EDIT:**
Ah, sorry I missed you mentioning you're using WPF. Unfortunately Membership provider is ASP.NET specific and isn't available in WPF.

Comment: I think it would still be fairly trivial to use the membership tool to create the DB objects, then build your own models from that.

Comment: @agrothe Have you looked at the tables membeshipservice creates?

Comment: @Blam, yes, I modified them to create a hybrid auth service that used a shared db user for authenticating users, then switched to sql server auth once verified. Only a few of the tables are actually needed to implement a solution.

Answer (score -2):

Business application with solid security and roles.
If the client is hitting the database directly then that SQL connection and those SQL credentials can be hacked.

[Windows Communication Foundation Authentication Service Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx)

[WPF Security Strategy - Platform Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743612.aspx)

You can still use EF as the backing for the roles and logins.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but you didn't answer the question. Valid concern? sure, but at least answer the question in your response.

Comment: @agrothe Business application with solid security and roles.  I will clarify.